# Terminal styling (control chars) using the chalk NPM module

Tags: node.js, npm, control-characters, chalk

Say I have this:

```
//exp.js
const chalk = require('chalk');
console.log(chalk.red('foobar'));
```

and then I run at the command line:

```
node exp.js | cat
```

In all the cases I have seen, the colors won't show up. Does anyone know why? Is there a way to get the colors to show up? Am I doing something wrong?

My only guess is that the [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/blob/master/index.js) library "turns off" the string styling when the processes are hooked up in a pipe?

For example:

[image]

Comment: Here's the chalk  library source - https://github.com/chalk/chalk/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Don't comment your question, but do edit it for improvement

Comment: I prefer to fill up the comments, and keep the question tidy

Comment: people look to comments if they need more info

Comment: They should not. Comments on questions are reserved to others. I edited your question to add the link, but you should have done that.

Comment: BTW, that library (which I am discovering) *documents* that it "auto-detects color support". I suggest to add an issue in their github.

Comment: I added a screenshot for clarity

Comment: Here is the issue on Github: https://github.com/chalk/chalk/issues/212

Comment: That issue URL should also go into the question. Basically, you should forbid yourself to comment your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the fine manual](https://github.com/chalk/chalk#chalksupportscolor):

```
$ node exp.js --color | cat
$ env FORCE_COLOR=1 node exp.js | cat
```

Or:

```
//exp.js
process.env.FORCE_COLOR = '1';
const chalk = require('chalk');
console.log(chalk.red('foobar'));
```

Comment: oh yes, that must be it